# Pending in Next.js but everything works in Postman

Tags: express, next.js, vercel

Why does this POST function work fine with Postman, but with Next.js I get pending in the debug console?

route in express:

```
 //CREATE NEW USER
 export const newUser = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
 const user = new User({ ...req.body.user });

 const savedUser = await user.save();

  res.status(200).json(savedUser);
  } catch (error) {
 res.status(200).json("ERROR");
  }
};
```

main.ts:

```
useEffect(() => {
const storeUser = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.post("/api/new", { user }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
if (Object.keys(user).length !== 0) {
  storeUser();
 }
}, [user]);
```

/api/new.ts

```
 export default async function handler(
 req: NextApiRequest,
 res: NextApiResponse
 ) {

  await fetch("https://.../server/user/new",options).then((result)=>{
      console.log(result.json())
    })
})
```